# How do I retrieve the full object from a selected item in dropdown that was filled by an observable array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Suppose I had the dropdown list:

```
<select id="department-options" 
data-bind="options: departments, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'DepartmentId', value: departmentId" />
```

And this dropdown list is bound to a complex object via knockout js:

```
this.departmentId = ko.observable();
this.departments = ko.observableArray([]);

this.setDepartments = function(){
    $.get('myserviceurl', departments);
}
```

The list fine and the value is updating the departmentId in the view model just fine. The thing is that the service actually returns a list of objects that contain several properties. The binding for the dropdown list only defines where to get the text, where to get the value, and what to do with the selected value. There are some other things that I would like to do with the other members of those objects on selection change.

So for instance, if the objects loaded into this.departments contained a property called subdepartmentOfId, how can i retrieve that property of the currently selected item in the list? My first instinct is to grab the selected index and find it in the observable array, but that sounds unreliable and it seems like there would be a much easier way to do this.

Comment: If the question is bad, then state why the question is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out almost as soon as I posted:

```
<select id="department-options" 
data-bind="options: departments, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: $root, value: selectedDepartment" />
```

Changed the optionsValue to `$root` then access properties via `this.selectedDepartment().subdepartmentOfId`